# How can I see if a child exists in Python?

Tags: python

I have an `lxml` object called `item` and it may have a child called `item.brand`, however it's possible that there is none as this is returned from an API. How can I check this in Python?

Comment: do you mean "class child" by a word "child" or a "class method"?

Comment: When they call home and ask for money, then you know theyexist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `hasattr()`.

Comment: Specifically hasattr(item, 'brand') returns a True if lxml_obj exists and False otherwise.